# REGEX Failures; a pattern known to be there not being found

Tags: regex

I have a piece of code that searches through protein sequences for particular patterns. It is comprised of an array of regular expressions that I modify as needed. But I just noticed that the regex is missing sequences I know to be there.

Here is the array, and the pattern CARRAGCAGAARCRCAACRR is not found by it.

```
'[G|C]........[A|R].[A|C|R][G|A|R][A|R].....[A|R][A|R]',
'[G|C]...[A|R]......[A|R]........[G|C][A|R][A|R]',
'[G|C]...[A|R]......[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][A|R]',
'....[A|R]......[A|R].[R]......[A|R]',
'[G|C]..........[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][R]',
'....A..A...R.......R',
'..A....A...R.......R',
'..A.A......R.......R',
'..A.A..A...........R',
```

Thanks for any guidance!

EDIT:

**This is being done in javascript.**

Here is the code in question:

```
  (function(seq){
   var seq_str = '',
         results = {},
         patterns = [
            '[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R]........[G|C][A|R][A|R]',
            '[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][A|R]',
            '....[A|R]....[A|R].[R]......[A|R]',
            '[G|C]........[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][R]',
            '....A..A...R.......R', //THIS SHOULD FIND IT!!!
            '..A....A...R.......R',
            '..A.A......R.......R',
            '..A.A..A...........R',
            ],
```

Thanks to everyone who is still paying attention. I know this is being downvoted, but I'm not a coder, so your continued help is VERY appreciated!

That line marked should find the match. If I comment out all other lines except that line, I can match the string.

Comment: Yes, your input is matched by `....A..A...R.......R`. So if it goes unmatched, there seems to be a bug in the surrounding code of yours. Nothing more to say without more information.

Comment: php > var_export(preg_match("[....A..A...R.......R]", "CARRAGCAGAARCRCAACRR"));
1
(so, it's something else)

Comment: I agree, it 'should' be found!

Here is the rest of the code:
`'(function(seq){
var seq_str = '',
        results = {},
        patterns = [
                '[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R]........[G|C][A|R][A|R]',
                '[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][A|R]',
                '....[A|R]....[A|R].[R]......[A|R]',
                '[G|C]........[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][R]',
                '....A..A...R.......R',
                '..A....A...R.......R',
                '..A.A......R.......R',
                '..A.A..A...........R',
                ],`

Comment: Is it in `PHP` or `JS`?

Comment: You should [edit] your question when you want to add information

Comment: Just a slight note - it would be helpful if you had mentioned which of the regex'es in your list you'd expect to match. It's a bit cruel having your readers match all of those in wetware...

Comment: There are two other that will match your string `[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][A|R]` and `[G|C]........[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][R]`

see my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming language is `JS`, it is working as shown. Maybe you forgot to change your string to `regex` using `RegExp object constructor`

```js
var patterns = [ '[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R]........[G|C][A|R][A|R]', '[G|C]...[A|R]....[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][A|R]', '....[A|R]....[A|R].[R]......[A|R]', '[G|C]........[A|R].[A|R]......[A|R][R]', '....A..A...R.......R', '..A....A...R.......R', '..A.A......R.......R', '..A.A..A...........R', ]
var line = "CARRAGCAGAARCRCAACRR"

for (x in patterns) {
   if (line.match(new RegExp("\\b" + patterns[x] + "\\b"))) {
      document.write(x + patterns[x]);
   }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/MZmjTF)**